# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app' even though __init__.py present

Tags: python, importerror

I have been struggling with importing a particular file from a sibling directory. The structure is as follows:

```
app/
   __init__.py
   main.py
   database/
      __init__.py
      crud.py
      db.py
      models.py
      schemas.py
      ...
   utils/
      __init__.py
      ...
   telegrambot/
      __init__.py
      actions.py
      bot.py
   twitterbot/
      __init__.py
      ...
```

I am trying to import `crud.py` in `database/` from within `telegrambot/bot.py`. However no matter which import statement I try, I can't seem to be able to import the file.

1. `from app.database import crud` **==>** `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`
2. `from ..app.database import crud` **==>** `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

I tried some others as well like `from database import crud` and they don't work as expected.

I have never really worked with an app of this structure so this is kinda new to me. Really wish soomeone can point me in the right direction. I do not wish to use `import sys`.

For completion sake, I am using Python 3.8.5.

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

import .database.crud

Comment: This was actually one of the statements I already tried. I get the same error as number 2 in my original post:

```ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package```

Comment: this is wierd. what about :  import .database.crud

Comment: That just generates a SyntaxError. ```import .database.crud SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: from .database.crud import *   ?